# Random REST API calls fail after upgrading Jersey version

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey-2.0

Recently had to upgrade version of Jersey from 2.5.1 (reason explained later) to 2.7 and ever since the upgrade, every time I upload code to the server, random API calls start failing with the following stacktrace:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [com.example.rest.LeaderboardApi] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.hasInjectAnnotation(Utilities.java:1484)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerMethods(Utilities.java:1425)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:239)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitMethods(Utilities.java:243)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:163)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:200)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:649)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:604)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:405)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2046)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$700(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$6.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1011)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$6.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1006)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1093)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:616)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:535)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:483)
        at com.example.config.JerseyFilter.doFilter(JerseyFilter.java:27)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:420)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
        implementation=com.example.rest.LeaderboardApi
        contracts={com.example.rest.LeaderboardApi}
        scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
        qualifiers={}
        descriptorType=CLASS
        descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
        metadata=
        rank=0
        loader=null
        proxiable=null
        proxyForSameScope=null
        analysisName=null
        id=156
        locatorId=0
        identityHashCode=1367521629
        reified=false)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:615)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:405)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2046)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$700(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$6.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1011)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$6.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1006)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1093)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:616)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:535)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:483)
        at com.example.config.JerseyFilter.doFilter(JerseyFilter.java:27)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:420)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Every time I do a clean build and re-upload, a new set of methods start failing (and the previously-failing ones start working) without any code change!

After trying 2.7, I switched to 2.25.1 and that opened up a whole another can of worms, so I tried with 2.5.2 (instead of the original 2.5.1) and it had the same problems as 2.5.1. I switched to 2.8, and it had the same random issues as with 2.7.

Current status is that with either version 2.7 or 2.8, a small (at least seemingly) random subset of the REST API methods fails with messages similar to the one above.

I would like to find out why this is and fix it.

#### Method Followed While Switching Jersey Versions

I would clean out the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, change the `jersey.version` variable in `pom.xml` to the new version. Eclipse would then fetch all the necessary libs and re-build code. Running `mvn appengine:update` would re-populate the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and package everything up.

A few times I did a clean (full) build to ensure that no artefacts from different versions would get mixed.

#### Reason for Upgrading from 2.5.1

Had to add a method (with the following signature):

```
public Response importChildren(@Context ContainerRequestContext reqCtx,
        @PathParam(ID) String id, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream csvStream,
        @FormDataParam("test") String testStr)
```

that would take an `InputStream` of a CSV file and process that. Because of that had to add `jersey-media-multipart`. Used with version 2.5.x (haven't tried with 2.6), this starts giving an error because it tries to write the `InputStream` to a temporary file (writing to disk is prohibited in Google App Engine (Standard), which is what I am using).

With versions >= 2.7 this tendency to write a temporary file can be avoided by adding file `jersey-multipart-config.properties` with the content `jersey.config.multipart.bufferThreshold = -1`

#### A Desperate Workaround

If nothing else works, I could move the CSV processing code out of Jersey-mediated methods and into a simple servlet. Then I don't need `jersey-media-multipart` and can move back to using version 2.5.1, where all the code was working reliably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.hasInjectAnnotation(Utilities.java:1484)
```

is a [known bug](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2731) of interoperation between Jersey and particular underlying HK2 kernel version, which comes with Jersey 2.7 as transitive dependency

> We've switched to HK2 2.3.0-b05 in 2.9-SNAPSHOT. After we release 2.9 the problem should be gone.

Looks like the closest Jersey version which has that bug fixed is `2.9`. But if you'd prefer to stay with 2.7 please find below workaround.

To force usage of `hk2-api 2.3.0-b05` version through Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <!-- this is to exclude 2.2.0 version -->
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b05</version>
</dependency>
```

That exclusion exercise may be required for some of the rest Jersey artifacts in your pom.xml, just check the `mvn dependency:tree ...` accordingly

Comment: I switched to Jersey 2.9 (which pulled in hk2-api-2.3.0-b05.jar, hk2-locator-2.3.0-b05.jar, hk2-utils-2.3.0-b05.jar) and so far haven't seen that problem, but now on at least two methods I am getting 415 (Unsupported Media Type) errors: `org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor aroundReadFrom: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.example.json.StarDto, genericType=class com.example.json.StarDto` . Almost all my POST/PUT methods have `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. These were working with 2.5.1.

Comment: Does Jackson have to be upgraded from version 2.7.1?

Comment: For your 2.9 exception, looks like the following should be added to your pom.xml
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: Yes, I tried that soon after writing my comments, and now I am getting: `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;)`. Seems to be on every method that's `POST`.

Comment: Can you check which version of `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs: 
  jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` is being packed during the build? Looks like less than 2.6 where such constructor was introduced.  Seems to be another <runtime> statement to be added to your pom.xml

Comment: I had to stop `jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar` from being pulled in by `jersey-media-json-jackson` to get my code to work. See my detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

## The Full and Complete Solution

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45895036/91933) by [@Kostiantyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8513835/kostiantyn) set me on the right path, though I had to make a small change to get it to work. So that others can avoid the time wastage that I had to face, I will give the complete solution below.

As @Kostiantyn pointed out, I needed to upgrade to Jersey 2.9 to get rid of the interoperation bug between Jersey and HK2. However, when I switched to 2.9 I started getting the following error on all my POST/PUT methods (all of which `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecu‌​tor$TerminalReaderIn‌​terceptor aroundReadFrom:
  MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.example.json.StarDto,
    genericType=class com.example.json.StarDto
```

This was a big problem and to solve this I added the following dependency (based on suggestion by @Kostiantyn):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

After testing with this new added dependency, the older errors were gone and instead I started getting the following on my POST methods (didn't test the PUT methods):

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.<init>(Lc‌​om/fasterxml/jackson‌​/databind/cfg/Mapper‌​Config;
```

After trying a lot of different things I finally realised that `jersey-media-json-jackson` was pulling in the `jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar`, which was conflicting with jackson-jaxrs-base-**2.7.1**.jar (which was the version I needed). So adding `jersey-media-json-jackson` with the following exclusion finally solved all my problems:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had exact same problem when trying to deploy my application to a weblogic server.

**Restarting the weblogic managed server worked for me**.

**To stop:**

Start WebLogic Server administration console by typing http://[host name]:[port]/console in the URL line of a web browser.

Under Domain Structure, click Environment > Servers.

In the right pane, click the Control tab.

Select the managed server that you want to stop.

Click the Shutdown button below the managed server you want to stop.

Select When Work Completes to gracefully shut down the server or select Force Shutdown Now to stop the server immediately without completing ongoing tasks.

On the Server Life Cycle Assistant pane, click Yes to complete the shutdown.

**To start:**

Ensure that the WebLogic Server and Node Manager are running.

Start WebLogic Server administration console by typing http://[host name]:[port]/console in the URL line of a web browser.

Under Domain Structure, click Environment > Servers.

In the right pane, click the Control tab.

Select the managed server that you want to start.

Click the Start button below the managed server you want to start.

Comment: Glad I read this before trying to tear apart all the dependencies and redo everything! Worked for me on my local integrated server also.